# AOSP Mirroring Error

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

I want to mirror AOSP repository so i did the following

```
mkdir ~/bin
curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
export http_proxy=http://xx.x.x.x:808/
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
~/bin/repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/mirror/manifest --mirror
~/bin/repo sync -j6
```

Everything works fine until it downloaded 60GB then it is giving following error

**fatal: unable to access 'https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/clang/linux-x86/mips/3.3/': Proxy CONNECT followed by 269 bytes of opaque data. Data ignored (known bug #39)**

Just before starting this download i tried to mirror **android-4.4.2_r1** branch which another 50GB downloaded from google

Im sure my proxy server is working. Is it something google is blocking me or what could be the reason for this how can i resolve this.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes google blocked me after downloading 100GB from google servers , this [official document](https://source.android.com/source/downloading) gave me a hint about quota size .I used  authenticated access by following the instructions given in the document and it starts again thanks to the repo tool for downloading the remaining projects where it left off.